# How to import a local module into azure databricks notebook?

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to use a module in databrick's notebook but I am completely blocked. I'd like to execute the following command or anything similar which allow my to make instances of `MyClass`

```
from mypackage.mymodule import MyClass
```

Following databrick's [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/libraries.html#referencing-libraries) I have develop a python package with a single module locally as follows:

```
mypackage
|- __init__.py
|- setup.py
|- mymodule.py
```

Then run `python setup.py bdist_wheel` obtaining a `.whl` file. The directory ends up being

```
mypackage
|- build
   |- ... whatever
|- src.egg-info
   |- ... whatever
|- dist
   |- src-0.1-py3-none-any.whl
|- __init__.py
|- setup.py
|- mymodule.py
```

From here I've uploaded the `.whl` file into the *Workspace* following the instructions. But now I'm not able to import `MyClass` into any notebook.

I've tried all approches below:

- upload the `.whl` with and without a name.
- upload the `.whl` installing it into the cluster and not.
- use `import mypackage`
- use `dbutils.library.install('dbfs:/path/to/mypackage.whl/')` (which returns `True`) and then use `import ...`
- instead of uploading a `.whl`, create the package folder in the same directory as the notebook.
- Upload to my folder and to `Shared` folder
- all combinations of the above. f.ex: uploading with different name and use `import differentname`

This is driving my crazy. I its such a simple task which I can achive easily with regular notebooks.

Comment: What does file setup.py contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this by using python's `egg` instead of `wheel`. `python setup.py bdist_egg` will create an egg which you can install following databricks docs. I don't know why `wheel` doesn't work...

Answer (score 3):

With the the introduction of *support for arbitrary files in Databricks Repos*, it is now possible to `import` custom modules/packages easily, if the module/package resides in the linked git repo.

First,

1. Make sure [Repos for Git integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/repos) is enabled.
2. Make sure [support for arbitrary files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/repos#enable-support-for-arbitrary-files-in-databricks-repos) is enabled.

Both of these can be enabled from Settings -> Admin Console -> Workspace Settings.

Then, with the following directory structure in the git repo,

```
.
├── mypackage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── mymodule.py
└── test_notebook
```

it is possible to `import` the module `mymodule` in the package `mypackage` from `test_notebook` simply by executing the following statement:

```
# This is test_notebook in the above filetree
from mypackage.mymodule import MyClass
```

Comment: To me this simply give error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypackage'

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else trying to solve this in a Databricks Workspace, without using Repos, the key seems to be ensuring your module code is a **File** and **not a Notebook**.

Here is a minimal example, which works for me on the 12.2 LTS runtime.

**testmod.py:** (File, not Notebook)

```py
def hello():
    print ('Hello')
```

**Any Notebook in the same folder:**

```py
import testmod
testmod.hello()
```

If your module is in a subfolder/package called `testpackage`, you can do:

```py
from testpackage import testmod
testmod.hello()
```

If you are uploading your code via the API or CLI, you can make it a File rather than a Notebook by following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77580533/19734178.